# Normal distribution with P(x=a) and P(x≥a)

Tags: normal-distribution

> Given: height of $1000$ students normally distributed with $\mu=174.5\,\mathrm{cm}$, $\sigma=6.9\,\mathrm{cm}$
>
> Find: a. $P(x<160\,\mathrm{cm})$ b. $P(x=175\,\mathrm{cm})$ c. $P(x\geq188\,\mathrm{cm})$

For a., I used the formula $z=x-\mu/\sigma$, which gives $-2.10$. Looking at the $z$ table, I derived $0.0179$.

However, for points b. and c. I cannot find any reference on how to solve "equal to" and "greater than or equal to" probabilities related to normal distribution. We only discussed $P(z < a)$, $P(z > a)$ and $P(a < z < b)$.

Comment: Hint:  $P(x≥a)=1-P(x<a)$.  Also, in a normal distribution the probability of getting one specific value exactly is always $0$.

Comment: Were you taught the properties of a continuous distribution?

Comment: @lulu thanks! how about for P(x=a)?

Comment: @joel we were noted only on greater than, less than and 'in between' problems, without any example on 'equal to' problems

Comment: "the probability of getting one specific value exactly is always $0$", that's what lulu wrote and that still holds...so $P(x=a)=0$

Comment: You were not trolled.  You were tested if you understood the concepts.

Comment: You better check your table again.  For $z=-2.10$, you should get a probability of around $0.0179$, not $0.0222$.  (The value that you got ($0.0222$) is for $z=-2.01$.)

Comment: I overlooked the mistake! thank you for rectifying

Comment: Now check your value for (c).

Comment: P(x≥188)= P(z<-1.96)= 0.0250

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 2):

One of the properties of a [continuous probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) like the normal distribution is that the probability of any individual outcome is zero.  This is true even if it is possible for that outcome to happen.

For example, it is possible that the height of a student is exactly 175 cm, but if you model height with a normal distribution, then the probability of that happening is zero.

Using this knowledge, you will find that $P(x\ge a)=P(x=a)+P(x>a)=0+P(x>a)=P(x>a)$.

Also note that if you were being asked for the probability, then your answer should be a number from $0$ to $1$.  (So your answer of $22$ is not a probability.)

Comment: oh sorry I forget to mention. the problem asks for how many students are expected to have heights less than 160 so I multiplied it by 1000